# Time series array finding peaks and valleys

Tags: algorithm

I've been working on a python code to mimic another's programs results for finding peaks. So far I have not been able to figure out the logic between these numbers to successfully get the correct output. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction to an algorithm that solves my problem?

Here's what it looks like: All numbers are arranged in the order left to right in sets of 3. The bold numbers are the peaks the program chooses using the 3 numbers in each set. Why are the bold numbers being selected? I have spent hours trying to figure it out and have got nothing...

0.31,      **0.40**,           0.45

0.31,      **0.45**,           0.40

**0.45**,     0.40,        0.31

**0.45**,     0.31,        0.40

**0.40**,        0.45,         0.31

**0.40,**   0.31,   0.45

Comment: What is this time series about?

Comment: Determining the peaks of stocks. "Find 3 peaks within 50 cents of one another & plot the most important one." You'd think it would use the median or some sort of average but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

One possible pattern is that it chooses the first number that starts with a 4

Comment: With the given information, this seems the most plausible answer.